# I keep getting the BadRequestKeyError 400, and I don't know why

Tags: python, html, flask, routes, bad-request

Python Side Routing

```
@app.route("/loginC", methods=["POST"])
def loginPage():
    valid = request.form["idnumber"]
    if valid is not None: #Creating A New User
        username = request.form["username"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        firstname = request.form["firstname"]
        lastname = request.form["lastname"]
        idnumber = request.form["idnumber"]
        logins["'"+username+"'"] = {"password":"'"+ password +"'", "firstname":"'"+ firstname +"'", "lastname":"'"+ lastname +"'", "idnumber":"'"+ idnumber +"'"}
        session["currentUser"] = username
        isLogin = True
        return redirect("/login")
    else:
        username = request.form["username"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        for account in logins:
            if username == logins:
                if logins["'"+username+"'"]["password"] == password:
                    session["currentUser"] = username
                    isLogin = True
                    return redirect("/login")
        return redirect("/login")
```

Html

```
<form action="/loginC" class="formLogin" method="post">
      <h3>Existing User</h3>
      Username: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required><br>
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
   <br>
   <hr class="formLogin">
   <br>
<form action="/loginC" class="formLogin" method="post">
      <h3>New User</h3>
      Username: <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required><br>
      Password: <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required> <br>
      Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname" required><br>
      Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="lastname" required><br>
      Student ID: <input name="idnumber" type="text" placeholder="ID number" required><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
```

I keep getting the error:
"werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'idnumber'"

it is requesting the form in the second for bracket aka the 'new user' bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of :

```
valid = request.form["idnumber"]
```

Change to :

If you want to retrieve POST data:

```
valid = request.form.get("idnumber")
```

If you want to retrieve GET (query string) data:

```
valid = request.args.get("idnumber")
```

Also :
Change method to

```
@app.route("/loginC", methods=["GET", "POST"])
```